# Faster way to simulate the crunch command behaviour on Python3.8

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to simulate what the crunch command does in Linux, with the difference of yield the words instead of writing them into a file and i came up with something like this:

```
def wordlist(chars, min, max = None):
    if max is None:  # Means that the user want only a singular length
        max = min

    length = len(chars)

    for n in range(min, max + 1):
        indexes = [0] * n
        for _ in range(length ** n):  # The length of all the chars to the power of the places to fill return the number of words in the wordlist
            for m in range(1, len(indexes) + 1):  # This is the reporting system, like if indexes instead of a list is a number
                if indexes[-m] == length:
                    indexes[-m] = 0
                    indexes[-m - 1] += 1
            yield ''.join(chars[i] for i in indexes)
            indexes[-1] += 1
```

It's a bit rude and not too much readable, maybe neither too much performing. Without using any external module like itertools, has someone got a better idea?

EDIT:

After a bit of struggling I have improved the math behind coming up to something like this:

```
def wordlist(chars, min, max = None):
    if max is None:
        max = min
    if min <= 0 or max <= 0:
        return

    base = len(chars)

    for n in range(min, max + 1):
        for m in range(base ** n):
            yield ''.join(chars[m // base ** (n - v - 1) % base] for v in range(n))
```

Anyway I measured the time taken by each of the two function and, while this new one is much more readable and pretty, the first one still faster. I still waiting for better ideas from you